# How to get firebase_app_id by app_instance_id?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-api

I get [app_instance_id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#public-taskstring-getappinstanceid)(FirebaseAnalytics) on the application side and give it to the backend.

Problem: we add 1 more app and don't understand which app app_instance_id belongs to.

Сan i get list of app_instance_id through firebase rest api?
Can i identify app by app_instance_id via firebase/google rest api?

Goal:[sent event google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=firebase)

I couldn't find in the documentation how to do it.
We thought about passing firebase_app_id through the client, but I really would not want to.